# Is it possible to track a link from a redirect link?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm creating a printed advert and would like to use a separate link on the campaign which redirects to my main site. My question is, is it possible to track this link using Google Analytics?

I currently have an alias on an existing website and when I tested to see if this works, it comes up as a direct link rather than a referral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would utilize [campaign tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en) for this.

Note, this redirect you're using, you have to only use it for print or dedicate it for print for the duration of this campaign at least.

First you have your redirect: `example.com/come`

This redirect would normally redirect to: `example.com/products/awesome-product`

To track this link as something other than direct, you'll need to add UTM parameters. The three important ones are Source (utm_source), Medium (utm_medium), Campaign (utm_campaign). The Source you can call it `fall-print-ads`. The medium should be `print`, and if this ad is part of an larger overall campaign with numerous tactics, you can call this ad `fall-2018-campaign`. Hopefull you're more creative with the campaign names.

So to create the tracked link, you'll assemble everything together and attach it as parameters:
`example.com/products/awesome-product?utm_source=fall-print-ads&utm_medium=print&utm_campaign=fall-2018-campaign`

Make your redirect redirect to the link above and you'll be able to track this.

Answer (score 0):

These are called vanity URLs. And below links explain how to track them:

http://www.caddelldesigns.com/blog/why-vanity-urls-how-to-track-in-google-analytics
https://optimal.marketing/blog/how-to-create-and-track-vanity-urls-in-google-analytics/